# How to get trackpad gestures (three finger drag, four finger expose, etc.) functionality in elementaryOS installed on macbook pro 2009

Tags: touchpad, macbook, elementary-project

I am trying to revive an older MBP (mid 2009) with elementaryOS. One of the things that I noticed is that the trackpad by default is pretty limited after the installation. I figured that I need to inst

Answer (score 0):

Gestures doesn't function without proper program and configuration. 
You can Install Fusuma. My Macbookpro2008 got it working.
https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma